# How put address (from ganache-cli client) as a parameters in constructor

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

Always, when I try to send parameters for the constructor function I use a migration file and where I´m trying to deploy the contract, add the parameters...Something like that:

```
var OVXET = artifacts.require("./OVXET.sol");


module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(OVXET, 1000000000, "OVXET", "OVX", accounts[1], accounts[2]);
}
```

But in this case...how I have to send the accounts? I want the same accounts that I am using the test files. Have I to incorporate a var initialized with web3.accounts?

Solution:

```
var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;
```

Is there another way to implement this task?

Comment: After try different things, the answer is create a var before module.exports using web3 features: var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;

Answer (score 1):

In [Truffle's documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations#available-accounts) they have an example how to access accounts from your ethereum client.

In your case it should be like this:

```
var OVXET = artifacts.require("./OVXET.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    deployer.deploy(OVXET, 1000000000, "OVXET", "OVX", accounts[1], accounts[2]);
}
```

The exported function has two additional parameters 'network' and 'accounts'.